# Show progress bar when downloading a file?

Tags: javascript, html, flask

When a user clicks on a file link, I want the download to start, and the webpage should also show a progress par, showing how much download is completed.

I saw this thing on google colab. See the screenshot:
[screenshot link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tBAv1.png) . The right side bar in the screenshot shows download progress.

In google colab, once the progress bar is 100%, the browser downloads the file in 1 second. I want something like this or just like normal download, the browser shows the download progress bar, but also the website shows it.

How can I do it? I am using Flask, Javascript, HTML to run the website. In my webpage, there are multiple download links, and I want to do it for all of them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `update()` and `scene()` functions of javascript for this.

```
function update() { 
  var element = document.getElementById("Your_div_id of progress bar comes here");    
  var width = 1; 
  var identity = setInterval(scene, 10); 
  function scene() { 
    if (width >= 100) { 
      clearInterval(identity); 
    } else { 
      width++;  
      element.style.width = width + '%';  
    } 
  } 
}
```

You may call the `update()` method by -

```
<button onclick="update()">Start Download</button>
```

Hope this helps :)